# How to import the navigator.notification.alert plugin PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, plugins

I am new to PhoneGap and my navigator.notification.alert won't work.
I think it is because I have not imported the navigator.notification.alert plugin but I  do not know how to in my set up.
Here is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "id"
    versionCode=""
    version   = "0.90">
    <name>Name</name>
    <description> Description </description>
    <author href="" email="">

    </author>
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.1.1" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="default" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
    <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="false" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="internalOnly" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
    <preference name="ErrorUrl" value=""/>
    <preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0x000000"/>
    <preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false"/>
    <preference name="LoadingDialog" value=","/> 
    <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <gap:platform name="ios" />
    <gap:platform name="android" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.Notification" />
</widget>
```

and here is my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-  1.4.5.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="pageLoaded();">
<div id="content">
<script type="text/javascript">
function onclick1() {
    navigator.notification.alert("Hi");
}
</script>
<p><input id="Button1" type="button" value="Test 1" onclick="return onclick1()" /></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function testAlert2() {
    navigator.notification.alert(
    "message",
    "title",
    "OK",
    {
        onClose: function(buttonIndex) {
            if (buttonIndex == 0)
                //doSomething();
            }
        }
    );
}
</script>
<p><a href="javascript: testAlert2();">Test 2</a></p>


<script type="text/javascript">
function Alert3() {
    navigator.notification.alert("message", function() {}, "title", "OK");
}
</script>
<p><a href="javascript: Alert3();">Test 3</a></p>


<script type="text/javascript">
function Alert4() {
    navigator.notification.alert('Title','Message','Button message');
}
</script>
<p><a href="javascript: Alert4();">Test 4</a></p>



</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In my config.xml, how would I import the navigator.notification.alert?
None of those alerts work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To add the plugin :**

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
```

**In your config.xml :**

```
<feature name="Notification">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
</feature>
```

**Example :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Notification Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Empty
}

// alert dialog dismissed
    function alertDismissed() {
        // do something
    }

// Show a custom alertDismissed
//
function showAlert() {
    navigator.notification.alert(
        'You are the winner!',  // message
        alertDismissed,         // callback
        'Game Over',            // title
        'Done'                  // buttonName
    );
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="#" onclick="showAlert(); return false;">Show Alert</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

[Details](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification)

Comment: I copied and pasted that code right before the <feature> I have in that code and nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: In nodejs? No, everytime I try to do the npm it says:

Comment: You can't use the plugin if you haven't added it with the command line.. writing the code in config.xml isn't enough

Comment: npm should be run outside of the node repl

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Thanks. What do I type in the command line? I'm so sorry for these questions.

Comment: Well, you should follow a tutorial or something. The link I provided can get you infos also check this link http://coenraets.org/blog/cordova-phonegap-3-tutorial/

Comment: I am following that tutorial and when I type that into the command prompt, it says that it is not a cordova based project.

Comment: It seems this tuto is an old one, check this one http://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/create-cordova-project.html and don't jump lines. You really can't have issues following this one, I mean this is from where I started also

Comment: Thanks a ton! Adding the plugin worked, but the code still does not work and I added your line of code to the new config.xml. I tried testing in the index.html. Then when I upload a zip file to build.phonegap.com it says my PhoneGap is out of date.

Comment: The code of your question is a mess, try a simple example such as the example there is inside the link of my answer